# List plugins used in a WP site - guest, not admin

Tags: plugins, list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to detect WP plugins used on a site](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3068/how-to-detect-wp-plugins-used-on-a-site)

Is there any way to list which plugins are used in a wordpress blog?

I am a guest - normal visitor of the site, not the admin!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can view the HTML source of the page and usually guess about some of them based on what is inserted into the page.