# Where can I find the corrent version of my wordpress blog?

Tags: updates, wordpress-version

Where can I find the corrent version of my wordpress blog ?

http://photoshop.faressoft.org

Answer (score 2):

Go to the dashboard of your WordPress admin, under 'Right Now' you will see the WordPress version you are using.

Answer (score 0):

http://photoshop.faressoft.org/readme.html and other signs (like version tags on scripts) say 3.1.1

This also should be listed in footer of admin interface.

Comment: Can Anyone know my version ?

Comment: @faressoft commonly yes, it can be hidden see ( [Steps to Take to Hide the Fact a Site is Using WordPress?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1507/steps-to-take-to-hide-the-fact-a-site-is-using-wordpress) ) but it takes some effort.

Answer (score 0):

**You're using 3.1.1**

Your WordPress version is outputted all over the place in the HTML header on the front-end of your blog. When you go to the dashboard, it should also give you the version number in the footer.