# What problems maybe happen if I remove "wp-" prefix from wordpress folders and files?

Tags: core, core-modifications

I want to hide wordpress signs from my site. So I don't want other people know that I built the website via WordPress. So I decided to remove `wp-` prefixes from all wordpress folders and files. And I also removed `wp-` prefixes from file contents with Notepad++. So my question is what problems maybe happen if I removed `wp-` prefixes ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Editing core is extremely bad practice. At best you will break updates, at worst random thing would be completely broken all over.

See [Steps to Take to Hide the Fact a Site is Using WordPress?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1507/steps-to-take-to-hide-the-fact-a-site-is-using-wordpress) for better alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the other answerers, that it's a bad idea to do what you've asked. However, you can rename the ***wp-content*** folder, and then point Wordpress back to it. 
For example, I rename my *wp-content* folder to *media*. If you take a look at the source code of smashingmagazine.com, you'll see media.smashingmagazine.com - this is their wp-content folder.

This article: http://sumtips.com/2011/01/move-rename-wordpress-wp-content.html explains it pretty well.

You can also rename the plugins directory - although I can't see why you'd need to do that.

**

### Doing this does cause problems with some plugins - I had to mod the NexGen gallery to work with this.

**

Answer (score 0):

The obvious issue is that you won't be able to update anything. I suggest taking a look at the [roots theme](http://www.rootstheme.com/) to see how you can make these modifications without touching core, which is never a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

This is a late reply, but I can give my feedback about this wordpress mod because I'm trying to achieve the same thing.

I've writed a [script](https://github.com/ziobru/wp-deprefix) that for now remove the wp- prefix from wordpress files and folders. During the debug I had a lot of problems with all the core files, this because the `wp-` prefix is used in various parts of the code. It can be an hard work to fix all the parts of the code, but it can be useful to learn how wordpress is structured and how to make important modifications to the core using plain php.