# Detecting a WordPress URL without doing a full HTTP GET?

Tags: urls

I'm trying to write a oneboxing routine that gives WordPress blog entries special treatment. So given a simple, unadorned URL in content, such as

> http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/a-new-name-for-stack-overflow-with-surprise-ending/

How would I detect that this is a WordPress installation, **ideally without doing a full HTTP GET on every URL I see?**

There are certainly common *conventions* for WordPress URLs that we could start with, which eliminates at least some URLs from contention. In this case it is ...

> http://example.com/year/month/slug-goes-here

But that isn't a universal constant either.

I tried looking at the headers of that URL using **HTTP HEAD**, and I see:

```
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:18340
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Thu, 07 Jun 2012 07:07:38 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=15, max=100
Server:Apache/2.2.9 (Ubuntu) DAV/2 PHP/5.2.6-2ubuntu4.2 with Suhosin-Patch mod_ssl/2.2.9 OpenSSL/0.9.8g
Vary:Cookie,Accept-Encoding
WP-Super-Cache:Served legacy cache file
X-Pingback:http://blog.stackoverflow.com/xmlrpc.php
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.2.6-2ubuntu4.2
```

I don't think relying on the presence of `WP-Super-Cache` would be particularly reliable, and that's the only thing I see in the headers that would help, so maybe there are zero common HTTP headers in a WordPress install?

Comment: To clarify - are you interested in .org self-hosted installs only or .com as well?

Comment: all WordPress installs -- any WordPress install

Comment: could you check for 200's on the associated RSS feed page?

Comment: Why exactly do you want this? Are false positives or false negatives worse? What about a site that generates the pages in Wordpress and exports a static dump of all pages periodically? (e.g. http://thespace.org/)

Answer (score 17):

From my experience and quick code search there are no *deliberate* ways WP identifies itself in headers. However there are some that seem distinct enough and not likely to be customized.

HEAD to `/wp-login.php` will contain following for .org install:

```
 Set-Cookie: wordpress_test_cookie=WP+Cookie+check; path=/
```

And for .com:

```
Set-Cookie: wordpress_test_cookie=WP+Cookie+check; path=/; domain=.wordpress.com
```

Cookie name is customizable by defining `TEST_COOKIE` constant, but `WP Cookie check` string is hardcoded in core, as well as `set_cookie()` call for this in the file's source.

For locating `wp-login.php` there are some URL shortcuts (implemented in [`wp_redirect_admin_locations()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_redirect_admin_locations/) since WP 3.4 (see ticket [#19607](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/19607) ):

`/login` on site's root does `302` redirect to `wp-login.php`, wherever it is.

So the only scenario that cannot be reliably detected if WP is installed in *and* confined to subdirectory, without being used to manage site's root at all.

Answer (score 12):

Send a `HEAD` request to `/wp-feed.php` in the same directory as `/xmlrpc.php` (even in subdirectory installations). In WordPress you will get a `Location` header as response containing the string `feed`.

In your example for `blog.stackoverflow.com` you’ll get:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently\r\n
Date: Thu, 07 Jun 2012 07:30:10 GMT\r\n
Server: Apache/2.2.9 (Ubuntu) DAV/2 PHP/5.2.6-2ubuntu4.2 with Suhosin-Patch mod_ssl/2.2.9 OpenSSL/0.9.8g\r\n
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.6-2ubuntu4.2\r\n
Location: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/feed/\r\n
Vary: Accept-Encoding\r\n
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n
\r\n
```

The bare existence of a file `xmlrpc.php` alone is not safe enough. Anybody can give this name to a file.

Caveat: The `X-Pingback` header can be disabled by filtering `'wp_headers'`. So my suggestion is not bullet-proof.

Related: [Steps to Take to Hide the Fact a Site is Using WordPress?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/1507/73)

Comment: wouldn't seeing `X-Pingback:http://example.com/xmlrpc.php` in the header be a strong enough signal to assume it's a WP blog?

Comment: This will work for "default" wordpress installs, but you can also run [wordpress in a subdirectory](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory), which would undermine this method.

Comment: @navitronic `xmlrpc.php` is always in the same directory as `wp-feed.php` as far as I can see.

Comment: X-Pingback is a standard(ish) header for any pingback-enabled resource, not just WP.

Comment: @NickFitz That’s why you should not rely on the xmlrpc file alone. Testing `wp-feed.php` is better.

Answer (score 6):

Append the URL with `?page_id=-1` and do an **HTTP HEAD** request for that.

On self-installed WordPress blogs, this will result in a 404 response.

On wordpress.com blogs, this will result in a 301 response (which ends up at a 200 response if you follow the redirect).

On non-WordPress sites, you should get a 200 response (assuming the original URL without the query string gave you a 200) - the query string should make no difference.

Example with a **HEAD** request for `http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/a-new-name-for-stack-overflow-with-surprise-ending/?page_id=-1`:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: Apache/2.2.9 (Ubuntu) DAV/2 PHP/5.2.6-2ubuntu4.2 with Suhosin-Patch mod_ssl/2.2.9 OpenSSL/0.9.8g
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Cookie,Accept-Encoding
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Last-Modified: Thu, 07 Jun 2012 08:53:01 GMT
Date: Thu, 07 Jun 2012 08:53:01 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100
Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Connection: Keep-Alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.6-2ubuntu4.2
X-Pingback: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/xmlrpc.php
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Example with a **HEAD** request for `http://dailycrave.wordpress.com/2012/06/01/three-cheese-grilled-pizza/?page_id=-1` (follow redirects turned off):

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
X-Pingback: http://dailycrave.wordpress.com/xmlrpc.php
Server: nginx
Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
X-Hacker: If you're reading this, you should visit automattic.com/jobs and apply to join the fun, mention this header.
Location: http://dailycrave.wordpress.com/2012/06/01/three-cheese-grilled-pizza/
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=60
Connection: close
Last-Modified: Thu, 07 Jun 2012 09:01:09 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Thu, 07 Jun 2012 09:01:09 GMT
```

(Note the X-Hacker easter egg!)

If you follow the 301 redirect for the wordpress.com blog, you end up with this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Vary: Accept-Encoding, Cookie
Last-Modified: Thu, 07 Jun 2012 09:48:26 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=172, must-revalidate
Connection: close
Date: Thu, 07 Jun 2012 09:50:34 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: Identity
Content-Encoding: gzip
Link: <http://wp.me/pXGqK-27g>; rel=shortlink
X-Pingback: http://dailycrave.wordpress.com/xmlrpc.php
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
X-Nananana: Batcache
X-Hacker: If you're reading this, you should visit automattic.com/jobs and apply to join the fun, mention this header.
```

Note the "Link" header containing the `http://wp.me/` URL, which seems to be common to all wordpress.com hosted blogs and could be used to identify them.

I believe this works because passing `?page_id=-1` in the URL overrides the default routing from the URL segments. There will not be a page with ID of -1, and so a 404/redirect is served instead.

Comment: I imagine any site out there can redirect or 404 at such URL, what behavior here is specific and identifies site as WP?

Comment: @Rarst Yes - that's the caveat. It's possible for sites to spoof this, and there may be some that use the `page_id` variable already. Any sort of detection method using headers can probably be spoofed, so I don't think it's worth worrying too much about that. Which just leaves false positives for custom CMS. I couldn't think of a more WordPress-specific variable that would be less likely to be used elsewhere. Is there one?

Answer (score 3):

Neither is wp-super-cache available on all wordpress installations, nor is there any fixed format in the URLs. While the permalinks settings page do give some fixed settings for URL schemes which can be used, anyone can just use any custom URL scheme.  For example, if anyone just decides to use only the page/post name in the URL, it is more or less impossible to figure out if it is a Wordpress website.

The presence of xmlrpc can be used to detect, but again, this can be disabled.

And finally, even if you do a full get on the URL, it is still not 100% possible to detect if the page is built using wordpress. It all depends on the theme template and how it is developed.

One fairly reliable way is to look for the presence wp-login and wp-admin. But even these could also be moved. I'd go for this way though.

Answer (score 1):

Two alternatives to the comments, set your own WordPress header. Drop this in your theme's functions.php.

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'add_wp_header');
function add_wp_header(){

header('Type: WordPress');
}
```

The WP scan fingerprinter (ruby), it goes through several steps to try and figure out if WordPress is being used such as looking for the plugin directory, theme name, meta tags, readme, etc (I have no idea how accurate this actually is).[http://code.google.com/p/wpscan/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Flib%2Fwpscan](http://code.google.com/p/wpscan/source/browse/#svn/trunk/lib/wpscan)

Answer (score 0):

How about sending a head request to one of the files starting with the prefix wp-. 
Ideally look at wp-login.php. If it exists that means the website is running WordPress.

Comment: `wp-login.php` could be located in a sub folder.

Comment: It could also be redirected and therefore renamed.