# Masking logout URL

Tags: functions, redirect, login, security, logout

The primary goal is to hide that the site is driven by wordpress. I've got the login part all locked up, but the logout URL still has those blasted `wp` delineators that give away it's a wordpress site.

Is there a way to somehow mask this URL? Perhaps by a conjunction of custom redirect where the client-side link goes to `www.site.com/logout/` but something in `functions.php` rebuilds the actual logout link?

I've tried variations of `wp_logout_url('$index.php')` but this only redirects. I've also tried

```
add_filter( 'wp_logout_url', 'cusotm_logout' );
function cusotm_logout() 
{
    // set your URL here
    return 'http://www.site.com/logout/';
}
```

Not only does this last one not work, it also appends `title=` to the end of the URL. I'm not sure if the logout doesn't work because of that or if the function itself is the wrong approach entirely.

I only use plugins if I absolutely have to. Looking for a self-managed solution... without needing to `mod_rewrite` if at all possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replacing just the URL is not enough. You have to tell WordPress what to do with the new URL.

Sample code, creates a log-out URL like `example.com/logout=1` and redirects to front page or custom URL after logging the user out:

```
add_filter( 'logout_url', 't5_custom_logout_url', 10, 2 );
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 't5_custom_logout_action' );

/**
 * Replace default log-out URL.
 *
 * @wp-hook logout_url
 * @param   string $logout_url
 * @param   string $redirect
 * @return  string
 */
function t5_custom_logout_url( $logout_url, $redirect )
{
    $url = add_query_arg( 'logout', 1, home_url( '/' ) );

    if ( ! empty ( $redirect ) )
        $url = add_query_arg( 'redirect', $redirect, $url );

    return $url;
}

/**
 * Log the user out.
 *
 * @wp-hook wp_loaded
 * @return  void
 */
function t5_custom_logout_action()
{
    if ( ! isset ( $_GET['logout'] ) )
        return;

    wp_logout();

    $loc = isset ( $_GET['redirect'] ) ? $_GET['redirect'] : home_url( '/' );
    wp_redirect( $loc );
    exit;
}
```

As [plugin on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/4288531), because this is **pure plugin territory**. And you [cannot](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/54437/detecting-a-wordpress-url-without-doing-a-full-http-get) [really](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1507/steps-to-take-to-hide-the-fact-a-site-is-using-wordpress) hide WordPress.

---

> it also appends title= to the end of the URL

I guess the problem is markup like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url(); ?> title="Log out">Log out</a>
```

Note the missing `"`.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you! I realize you can never hide wordpress completely, but there are certainly simple things you can do to make it less obvious for security reasons. I have a client who has recently been repeatedly hacked by bots, so I have been digging deeper into security precautions and anonymizing wordpress as much as possible.

Comment: I notice, though, that it still appends `title=` to the end of the URL. The logout function works, but do you know why it's appending it or if it can be removed?

Comment: This can only happen if you forgot a closing `"` or `'` in your markup somewhere.

Comment: In `login.php` or `functions.php`? I don't see any on either page, but will look harder.

Comment: @KristinaChilds See my update.

Comment: Ah-HA! It's very easy to miss those things in php shorthand. Thank you so much for your help. May you be showered in +1s :)