# Some plugins adding full server path after url (with custom wp-content folder)

Tags: plugins, 404-error, wp-config

Installing Wordpress SEO (an a few others but not all plugins) gives the following console error:

```
GET http://craigmdennis.com/content/plugins/nfs/c08/h04/mnt/152547/domains/craigmdennis.com/html/content/plugins/wordpress-seo/js/wp-seo-admin-global.js?ver=1.2.5 404 (Not Found)
```

For some reason it is listing the complete server path after my url.
It seems as though `/nfs/c08/h04/mnt/152547/domains/craigmdennis.com/html/content/plugins/` or 
`http://craigmdennis.com/content/plugins/` should not be present in the url.

Here is the directory structure (please note the custom content directory):

```
wp/
content/
content/themes/
content/plugins/
.htaccess
index.php
wp-config.php
```

I am not running MU.
I also have a subdomain for media (shouldn't be effecting the issue but I'm listing it for completedness)

Here are the relevant parts of my wp-config.php file:

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/wp');

define('WP_HOME',    'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);

define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/content');

define('WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/content');
```

Does anyone know what's going on here? Thanks.

[EDIT] I think it's related to `__FILE__` and not DOCUMENT_ROOT as the plugins all use `__FILE__` to get the directory name. This provides `/nfs/c08/h04/mnt/` instead of `/home/`.

When I echo the location of the [plugins_url()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url) I get `/home/152547/domains/dev.craigmdennis.com/html/content/plugins` which is correct but when I pass in **FILE** as a parameter I get the aforementioned `/nfs/c08/h04/mnt/152547/domains/dev.craigmdennis.com/html/content/plugins/{plugin-folder}`.

Could this be something to do with PHP resolving aliases for `__FILE__` This would explain why it works on my local server (with no aliases) and doesn't on Media Temple (which may alias `/nfs/c08/h04/mnt/` for `/home/`
Is this a Wordpress issue or an issue on my server?

Comment: We'll need to see more code here. Can include the bits specifically regarding the JS enqueue?

Comment: Based on @kalengi Answer, what if you also define `WP_PLUGIN_*`?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you mean the enqueue in my theme's functions.php of the enqueue used within the affected plugins?

Comment: @brasofilo I have tried explicitly defining WP_PLUGIN_DIR but have only just noticed WP_PLUGIN_URL can also be defined. I will try these again.

Comment: This Q&A may be useful: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/1507/12615

Comment: Right, I have isolated the error. If I place the full server path in WP_CONTENT_DIR the errors disappear. So it's the use of `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` that is the issue. Any suggestions on a replacement? Or should I just split it between the local-config.php and wp-config.php?

Comment: @Craig what about making use of ABSPATH that's also defined in wp-config.php?

Comment: @kalengi Can you elaborate please? The comment regarding ABSPATH states "Absolute path to the WordPress directory" which may not be relevant as I have a custom content directory.

Comment: `ABSPATH` is the actual physical path to the root of the WP installation so you could use it in place of `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`

Comment: @kalengi That's what I thought but my custom content directory is one level above the wordpress directory. I use wordpress as a git submodule; completely untouched.

Comment: @Craig actually `ABSPATH` holds is the path to the directory where **wp-config.php** is located. In your case, you can therefore use it to point to subdirectories: `ABSPATH . 'content'`

Comment: ABSPATH actually returns this: `/nfs/c08/h04/mnt/152547/domains/craigmdennis.com/html/wp/` which is the url of the install not `/nfs/c08/h04/mnt/152547/domains/craigmdennis.com/html/content` which contains my `wp-config.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is the result of the php `__FILE__` resolving any aliases or symlinks on the server.

The solution is to set `define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', dirname(__FILE__) . '/content');` so it is also the absolute file path on the server after resolving aliases.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php#104842

Answer (score 0):

Given that the js location is determined as follows:

```
$js_location = WPSEO_URL . 'js/wp-seo-admin-global.js'
```

where:

```
WPSEO_URL = WP_PLUGIN_URL . '/' . <WP_SEO_PLUGIN_PATH> . '/'
```

I suspect the problem lies with the derivation of `<WP_SEO_PLUGIN_PATH>`. This value is determined by the code in the function `plugins_url()` found in **wp-includes\link-template.php**

If you debug that function, it may yield the reason why `<WP_SEO_PLUGIN_PATH>` is producing the wrong value: *'nfs/c08/h04/mnt/152547/domains/craigmdennis.com/html/content/plugins/wordpress-seo'*

Comment: I doubt it is anything to do with the Wordpress core files or the plugin as it works fine locally. I think it is a server configuration issue or incorrect file path somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the example of Craig's solution, I've found a solution:

Craig posted this link that gives me some light about it:

> [See:
> http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php#104842](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php#104842)

Using the WP_PLGUIN_DIR global using my external plugin folder solved the issue.

I've declared this on my wp-config.php

```
define( 'WP_PLUGIN_DIR', '/var/www/name-of-the-external-folder/plugins' );
```

Hope it helps anyone here, It took me a while to discover.