# admin_print_styles incuding $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']

Tags: wp-admin, wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

All the Javascript isn't working in the admin area on my production server.

Locally it works fine. I have narrowed it down to /wp-admin/wp-header.php line 72-78

```
do_action('admin_print_styles');
```

And all similar ones to these.

The only difference on the production server is that I have set up a sym link:

```
ln -s /current/wp-content/plugins /shared/plugins
```

The symlink is working fine, I can access files by going to:

httt://productionsite.co.uk/wp-content/plugins/pluginname/file.css

However, when I view the console I get the following errors:

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://productionsite.co.uk/wp-content/plugins/var/www/vhosts/productionsite.co.uk/shared/plugins/wordpress-form-manager/css/style.css?ver=3.2.1"

So it is trying to include the wrong file and seems to have something to do with the sym link.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: See also [Plugins in symlinked directories?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15202/plugins-in-symlinked-directories) and http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/15484/73 for an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be facing a similar problem to this: [Some plugins adding full server path after url (with custom wp-content folder)](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/59299/some-plugins-adding-full-server-path-after-url-with-custom-wp-content-folder)

My first suggestion is to examine the value of `WP_CONTENT_DIR` and see whether it's what you expect. Not sure how the path could be getting mixed up, but I bet if you compare notes with @Craig about your respective server environments, then the cause might show up.