# Changing wp-content to other name? Multisite set up

Tags: multisite

Is there an easy way to change the words `wp-content` that show in the source code to `xyz-content` without breaking my site?
I want to do it for branding purposes.

I tried:

1. Url rewriting but the original `wp-content` still shows in the source code.
2. Doing a site download, find and replace and then re-upload but it takes over 24 hours with my server.
3. The plugin [Real-Time Find and Replace](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/real-time-find-and-replace/) changes the words from `wp-content` to `xyz-content` quickly, but the css etc does not load.

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: You tagged this Question as `<multisite>`. Are you trying this in a [WordPress Multisite](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) installation? If so, please edit your Q and add this information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can move the wp-content directory to a different location, which essentially renames it.

First, in your wp-config.php file, add this:

`define( 'WP_CONTENT_DIR', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/folder/path/to/new/dir' );`

And second, also in wp-config.php, add this:

`define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://yoursite.com/folder/path/to/new/dir');`

You can read more about changing the wp-content dir on the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Moving_wp-content).

Comment: Thanks @Pippin, nice and clean! It looks like it worked!

Comment: . Pippin and SamDom, check the [wp-hackers] part of this [answer of mine](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/58591/12615) regarding the safety of `$_SERVER`. . . . . . @SamDom Your Question only deals with one part of hiding/branding WordPress, that whole Q&A may be of your interest.

Answer (score 3):

Once you define WP_CONTENT_DIR and WP_CONTENT_URL ,your images may still uploaded to old wp-comtent/uploads path
to change this go to settings -> media and change the Store uploads in this folder url. Thats it