# How to Rename wp-login.php for Multisite?

Tags: multisite, wp-redirect

I want to hide and rename `wp-login.php` in my URL for branding purposes on a Multisite set up.

From this [forum post](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-change-from-wp-loginphp-to-login) I see that I can change `mysite.com/wp-login.php` to `mysite.com/login` by inserting a `RewriteRule ^login$ wp-login.php`  in my `.htaccess`. I like that the URL bar does not show login redirecting to wp-login.

If I try to login under a subsite `mysite.com/subsite1/login` it shows as redirecting from `mysite.com/subsite1/wp-login` to `http://mysite.com/subsite1/wp-login.php?privacy=1&redirect_to=%2Fsubsite1%2Flogin`

1. How do I get it to show as `mysite.com/subsite1/login` without the redirect in the URL bar?
2. If I enter `mysite.com/wp-login.php` it shows as page not found. Great!
   Now if I enter `mysite.com/subsite1/wp-login.php` it shows as the page exists. Oh no!
   How do I hide that this page exists for subsites? I tried the `functions.php` suggestion in my child theme but it created a redirect loop.

Comment: Please use proper formatting for code and virtual URLs. It makes reading the Q easier. You are aware that `/wp-login` doesn't exist, right? I normally orient my clients to login through `/wp-admin`, that redirects to `/wp-login.php`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things First ...

**The Rewrite Rule**
Basically all this rewrite says is (say it out loud) ... when I type `mysite.com/login` and hit enter, then take the user (rewrite) to `mysite.com/wp-login.php`

This is not a URL mask or URL Forwarding which is what you are hoping for.

Second Part ...

**After Login - Redirect too**
The url your are seeing contains 2 parts

1. `http://mysite.com/subsite1/wp-login.php`

   - this is the actual URL for the login page
   - as @Brasifilo says you are better of telling your customers to go to `mysite.com/wp-admin`
2. `?privacy=1&redirect_to=%2Fsubsite1%2Flogin`

   - ignore the `?privacy=1`
   - then `&redirect_to=%2Fsubsite1%2Flogin` is fairly obvious as where to GO after logging in successfully.

**Hiding that you're using WordPress**
It's probably better that your customers know that you have white labelled WordPress ... it would give more confidence that their CMS is a trusted open source application used by tens of millions of people around the world. Don't hide it :)

Comment: In the backend it doesn't make much sense hiding `/wp-login.php`. After all, what is going to be done with `/wp-admin/FILENAME.php`? Stripping **that** `wp-` out is simply not possible without heavily hacking the core, something that no sane WP developer is going to even consider. . . . If you want to brand, [theme the administration](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=admin+theme).

Comment: @brasofilo agree with you there ... BE PROUD to use WP :)

Comment: Obs.: even a small hack in the core is a big **no, no**. . . For the frontend, which IMO is a better place to hide that you're using WordPress, check [this Q&A](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/1507/12615). Haven't tested my technique in Multisite, but should work. . . . Damien, some clients explicitly ask for removing `wp-` traces in the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

I found this article a good reference and will be rolling out a few of the techniques and updating some old practices, based on the info within.

http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/wordpress/security-plugins-wordpress-bulletproof/

For re-writing login URL, Checkout Stealth login - I haven't used it so not sure if it works in a Multi-site but could be worth checking out.

And if your clients are worried about seeing WP in the URL, using Roots theme (or at least checking out its functions, could be handy too) http://www.rootstheme.com/