# How to completely hide a Wordpress/BuddyPress Install?

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation, bbpress

I want to make a bbPress application hide the fact that it is WordPress or bbPress for that matter. Please do not get me wrong. I am very proud of WordPress however I just do not want to make it easy for someone to snoop on my assets and version numbers etc for security purposes.

I have looked at some plugins that seem to do it for classic wordpress but was looking for a recommendation when it came to buddypress. Also I thought about renaming the theme folder etc.

Any tips?

Comment: Did you see [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1507/steps-to-take-to-hide-the-fact-a-site-is-using-wordpress)? There is handled the WordPress part, at least.

Comment: There is no reason to to this, it provides zero security.

Comment: I don't believe this question deserves the downvotes. It's perfectly valid to want to hide the backend details from would be hackers. Saying that though, I won't upvote simply because the question show's no effort.

Comment: It is not valid whatsoever, it would be the same as hiding your car's make and model and expecting that to protect it from being broken into.

Comment: @ wyk wow down vote for what? I asked a programmatic solution to a problem. you may not agree to why I would want it but that gives you no reason to down vote. It's the same as me saying hey your programming question is something i would never do but i will down vote. Learn some Stack overflow etiquette.

Comment: Perfectly valid question. Hiding implementation details is a perfectly acceptable way to thwart hacker attempts. If a hacker is unable to find out what platform you are running on, he/she may be unable to try to attempt certain attacks like zero day vulnerabilities. Also Just by renaming wp-admin and wp-login, most pre-configured bots will not be able to attack your site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see: http://codecanyon.net/item/hide-my-wp-no-one-can-know-you-use-wordpress/4177158    Sold 2300 copies ;)