# rename wordpress wp-includes folder in directory

Tags: development-strategy

how can we rename the wp-includes folder.We don't want folder name wp-includes displayed in source code

Comment: Maybe this is something for you? http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1507/steps-to-take-to-hide-the-fact-a-site-is-using-wordpress

Answer (score 1):

The name of `wp-includes` folder is hardcoded in multiple places on WordPress core, as well as `WPINC` constant which isn't conditional and can't be changed.

Renaming it would take creating and maintaining a fork of WordPress core, which is impractical.

Your best bet is just keeping it out of front end, for example by redefining any assets loaded from it to different URLs.