# How can I safely hide the fact that my website runs on Wordpress?

Tags: security, hacked, hacks

I would like to hide the fact that my website runs on Wordpress from potential hackers. Is there a reliable plugin that I can use, or an online guide to doing this, so that a website visitor would have no way to know it is a Wordpress site?

Comment: @toscho Is my question now suitable?

Comment: Sorry Marc, but it's 1. still too broad, 2. covered already in https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1507/steps-to-take-to-hide-the-fact-a-site-is-using-wordpress and 3. asking for a plugin recommendation which is off-topic for various reasons.